# How to have UILabel tap act like a UIButton to open URL

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, iboutlet

This is one of the first programming questions I asked, not realizing the diff between `UILabels` and `UIButtons`, regarding one of the most basic app operations. Of course the obvious answer in the comments is to just use `UIButtons`. However, rather than delete this answered question, if anyone can use Sh_Khan and the editor's ingenious code to make a `UILabel` act like a `UIButton` here it is:

```
// This is the label
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func loadView() {
super.loadView()

// This is the key
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onClicLabel(sender:)))
label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

// And that's the function :)
func onClicLabel(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
openUrl("http://www.google.com")
}


func openUrl(urlString:String!) {
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:    nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Anyway, my app has multiple buttons (error: here is where I did not originially perceive the diff between labels and buttons):

```
 @IBOutlet weak var labelONE: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var labelTWO: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var labelTHREE: UILabel!
```

Each of which is to open up a single corresponding URL:

```
openUrl("https://www.google.com")
openUrl("https://www.yahoo.com")
openUrl("https://www.twitter.com")
```

Comment: aren't you talking about `let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onClicLabel(sender:)))` ?

Comment: why don't you use buttons instead?

Comment: Yes, I expected to use buttons, however the most direct code I found here that worked used the label. I will experiment and make the change if all it takes is something like:  @IBAction func OpenDoc1(_ sender: UIButton) { openUrl("http://www.google.com") }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should better use buttons to handle things like that (`UIButton`) not labels (`UILabel`) , to solve your problem Try this

```
 // This is the key
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onClicLabel(sender:)))
label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

let tap2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onClicLabel(sender:)))
label2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
label2.addGestureRecognizer(tap2)

@objc func onClicLabel(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  if(sender.view == self.label)
  {
     openUrl("http://www.google.com")
  }
  else if(sender.view == self.label2)
  {
     openUrl("http://www.twitter.com")
  }
}
```

Comment: Sh_Khan your code works great. Just one curious thing I didn't mention about Jorge's initial code...when I pasted it in, Xcode required the following fix to "func onClicLabel(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {" : "Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'onClicLabel(sender:)' this is not exposed to Objective-C ... Add '@objc' to expose this instance to Objective-C ... So that after clicking on the fix button, the line is: "@objc func onClicLabel(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {" ... Not a problem, since it works, just seems odd to mention Objective-C when I'm using Swift.

Comment: yes this is swift 4 change for any selector method must append @objc before it